# Best way to structure this planets class

Tags: java

This is more a question about structure than coding. So i have a class named Planet and all planets have their modifiers for example: Is breedable? Damageable? etc. I already have a base planet class but i dont know how i will do that in a scalable way since i need to check if any planet has a certain modifier.

BasePlanet class:

```
public class BasePlanet {

    private String name;
    private String[] about;
    private long entranceTax;
    private boolean locked, pvp;

    private int minRank;

    private World planetWorld;
    private Location spawn;
    private Material icon;

    public BasePlanet() {
    }

    public BasePlanet(String name, int minRank, long entranceTax,
                      boolean pvp, boolean locked,
                      Material icon, String... about) {
        this.name = name;
        this.about = about;
        this.minRank = minRank;
        this.entranceTax = entranceTax;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.pvp = pvp;
        this.planetWorld.setPVP(pvp);
    }

    ... Getters and Setters
```

Implementing BasePlanet

```
public class Mars extends BasePlanet{

    public Mars() {
        super("Mars", 0, 0,
                true,
                false, Material.RED_SANDSTONE,
                "Este planeta contém pedras preciosas",
                "e itens especiais que nenhum outro planeta tem,",
                "ao menos que alguém tenha comercializado até",
                "este pequeno e cheio de surpresas, planeta vermelho."
        );
    }

}
```

**Solved**
Since i needed all modifiers to be required to have a name and a type I went through an easier way and i just created a class where it contained the 2 properties (name and type) and each modifier was extended by that class.

Modifier class:

```
public abstract class Modifier {

    private String name;
    private ModifierType type;

    public Modifier(String name, ModifierType type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ModifierType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ModifierType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public abstract void apply(Player player);
}
```

Gravity Modifier (example):

```
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class Gravity extends Modifier {

    private int gravity;

    public Gravity() {
        super("Gravity", ModifierType.ITEM_NEEDED);
    }

    public void apply(Player player){
        //TODO: apply gravity
    }
}
```

For the planet class i just added a new property to store all modifiers that needs to be included in the planet

```
private List<Modifier> modifiers;
```

Comment: Do your different derived classes actually have their own behaviour (i.e. their own methods, or override other methods from the base class)?    Based on the code you've posted, inheritance seems to be pointless, so perhaps you only need to create different instances of the same `Planet` class with different constructor arguments.

Comment: Yes they have their own methods. I didnt want to create different instances of the same Planet Class since in the future will be various modifieres and each planet can have more than one modifier

Comment: Depending on your needs, a component pattern may be useful. You could have an `Atmosphere` component, a `PVP` component, a `Material` component, etc. Then you can just have component containers that just happen to be planets.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962328/best-way-to-structure-this-planets-class "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: I still think you are better off with a single Planet class with a bunch of constant instances for each planet. Anything else will get messy quickly.

Comment: @Zymus Are you talking about composite pattern?

Comment: @tommyduarte no, the component pattern. You can read more if you look up entity component system. Although it might be beneficial if you mention that this is in the context of bukkit.

Comment: Your statement *"since i need to check if any planet has a certain modifier."* is quite unclear to me. What do you call "a modifier", and in your example I don't see any code which checks something for every planet. Can you please edit your question and clarify this before it gets closed as "unclear"?

Comment: @DocBrown wasnt supposed to be a friendly community?.... Sorry if im trying to enjoy my last days of vacations

Comment: @tommyduarte: I could have actually downvoted your answer immediately without a comment (like the most other downvoters already did), since that is what the downvote button is for: to mark unclear questions (nothing personal). Instead, I gave you a lot of time to fix the issues, But when you missed that chance, I finally downvoted it. Do you think that's unfriendly because I told you about it? I guess the downvoters which did not leave a note here are much more unfriendly. By the way, if you fix the question, you still have a chance to turn those downvotes into upvotes,

Comment: @DocBrown hmm ok, im getting used to this things like upvotes, downvotes etc sorry. Question edited.

Comment: @tommyduarte: thanks, but is there now an actual question left in your question?

Comment: @DocBrown aaa i think not xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need inheritance here. Since you don't need it, don't use it. Inheritance brings its own complexities and problems.

You are already doing a sort of composition typing with `MaterialType`. You didn't make a different base class for every kind of material, why do you need to do it with every particular planet?

```
Planets
{
    readonly static Planet MARS = new Planet("Mars", 0, 0, "ect");
    readonly static Planet VENUS = new Planet("VENUS", 0, 0, "ect");
 }
```

If you need multiple instances of a particular planet, the the you can have a planet type.

```
PlanetInstance
{
     PlanetType typeOfPlanet;
}

Planet mars1 = new PlanetInstance(PlanetType.MARS, "ect");
```

Comment: Im using inheritance because i know that i need to have various planets but with different attributes (one can be composed with gravity, other can have radiation etc) and i the players can have their own private planets with X attributes (im using a minecraft server api to manage that by GUI's).

Comment: Suppose you have 8 different binary attributes for a planet. You could plan to create 256 class which you might or might not use, or one class which could have up to 256 different instances. The second approach is more generic.

Comment: @tommyduarte: if you model what we all have in mind with planets, then every planet can have a gravity and a radiation attribute (set them to zero if you have such cases). Thus for these examples you don't need inheritance. The biggest problem with using inheritance for concrete planets, however, is, that it disables your program's ability to change the attributes at run time - inheritance is a compile time mechanism. And if different players can have their own private planets, you will probably need that ability.